# train / validation / test split problem

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, train-test-split

Suppose that I have created train/validation/test splits for model building.

I optimized the hyperparameters using the validation set and chose the parameter values which gave the highest accuracy. To estimate the accuracy in the production, I test the model on the test set.

Now, suppose that at a later time, I decided to do a more comprehensive parameter optimization and run experiments with a larger set of parameters. Suppose that I find a set of parameter values which lead to a higher accuracy on the validation set than the one in my previous trial. So now I decide to update my model in the production. But again to estimate the accuracy in the production, I test the model on the test set. However, test set accuracy turns out to be lower than the previous model's test accuracy.

If I do not update my model, I'm effectively using the test set as a validation set.

What is the best practice for these types of situations?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you have done, but there is a possibility that "a more comprehensive parameter optimization ...  higher accuracy on the validation set ..." is a way of saying "overfitting to the validation set"

Comment: It might be overfitting to the validation set or might not be. My question is rather about how to use the test set. According to the common literature, test set is used for assessing final model performance not for parameter tuning. But it you decide not to use your model because of test set performance than effectively you are using it for parameter tuning.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects:

1. Purpose of the test data: Use it mainly as information, not for decision. So in your case, you would typically go for the new model, even if its test performance is lower. The test performance helps you to judge *how* well the new model is expected to perform on data not used for modeling.
2. Aggressive tuning: The more intensely you use the validation data for hyper-parameter optimization, the more biased will be the validation performance. This starts to become a real problem when you compare the performance of such a model with a simpler one (e.g., with your first model or an additive model). The comparison is unfair. One way to overcome this problem is to use cross-validation for hyper-parameter tuning, and the validation data only to compare the tuned algoritms (e.g., XGBoost versus additive model).

Side remark: model selection should be done on a proper scoring rule like log loss. It is one of the most strange things that people use log loss/cross-entropy as loss/objective, and then make decisions with a very different and worse quantity.